# How to use optional parameters with QAxFactory based API

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently implementing an QAxFactory based COM-Api and want to give some of the functions default parameters. However, this seems not to work since when I call said functions without these default parameters I receive an error (HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)).

I found some advice about linking signals and slots within a program (like linking QML and C++ code https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html)
but that's not what I'm looking for and I don't how or if I can use that for my case. A minimal example:

```cpp
public slots:

void function (QString foo, bool bar = false); //so providing bar when calling function should be optional
```

When calling this (in my case from Visual Studio, where I write unit tests in c#), I find this:

```c
Api.function ("bla", true); //this works
Api.function ("bla"); //this gives the above error
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I'd appreciate feedback to the question style since this is my first question ever here.

Comment: This is because there are no such things as optional/ default parameters like you did. After compilation these methods will require all parameters but all invocations will have those default parameters already filled in by the compiler. Maybe try overloading instead of optional parameters

Comment: Since default parameters are described in the link I provided I was hoping that I could somehow use this in my case as well. If that's not possible than overloading has to do it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, here to help. I'll quickly write up an answer with some sources so that future viewers don't have to read the comment (which might get deleted by the automatic system)

Comment: Thanks again: One short question: What did you change in my code snippets? When reviewing your edit proposal I couldn't see a difference.

Comment: I didn't change any code. You had a few too many backticks ( ` ) around your code snippets, there should be three. I also added language specifiers to the snippets (c# and c++) so that the SO Syntax highlighter doesn't have to guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because optional parameters don't exist. Methods with optional parameters get compiled to standard methods without optional parameters.

But then, how do they work? Well, you see the compiler doesn't only change the method with the optional parameters, but also changes the code invoking the optional parameters. Take this code as an example:

```cs
using System;

namespace OptionalParameterDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OptionalParameters();
            OptionalParameters("Bar");
        }

        private static void OptionalParameters(string foo = "Hello World")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Using a decompiler like SharpLab we can see the decompiled source. And lo and behold we see that the OptionalParameters call was altered:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
namespace OptionalParametersDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Notice how this changed to include "Hello World"
            OptionalParameters("Hello World");
            OptionalParameters("Bar");
        }

        private static void OptionalParameters(string foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

So if we would now use something like P/Invoke to call the method `OptionalParameters` and not supply it with a parameter (as we think it's optional) it would throw an exception, so instead of using optional parameters we need to use an overload, so the parameter has a constant